# Rows not filtering when writing to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, export-to-csv

This code is used to find late deliveries for a certain range of time ( In this example, the year 2018 ) and to write the data into a csv file (otdedit.csv). However, although the data is filtering out correctly by year, the values that are not late deliveries are not being filtered out. My question is, how do I filter out the rows that only have late deliveries to be written into the csv file otdedit.csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


PURCHASE_ORDER = 'Material'
DELIVERY_DATE = 'Delivery Date'
DESIRED_DATE = 'Desired Delivery'
DELAYED_DAYS = 'Delayed Days'

df = pd.read_csv('otd.csv', index_col=PURCHASE_ORDER)

df[DELIVERY_DATE] = pd.to_datetime(df[DELIVERY_DATE])
df[DESIRED_DATE] = pd.to_datetime(df[DESIRED_DATE])
df[DELAYED_DAYS] = df[DELIVERY_DATE] - df[DESIRED_DATE]
late_threshold = pd.Timedelta(days=0)
late_deliveries = df[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold
df[late_deliveries].drop([DELIVERY_DATE, DESIRED_DATE], axis=1)



df['Delivery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['Desired Delivery'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Desired Delivery'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df2 = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year >= 2018) & (df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= 2018)]
df2['Diff Deliv Date'] = df2['Delivery Date'] - df2['Desired Delivery']




df2.to_csv('otdedit.csv', sep=',')
```

Here is a snap of otdedit.csv, notice how the rows with 0 delayed days are still appearing.

[image]

(Also as a side note, I don't know why this program is not filtering by headers too, I only wish for these 4 columns to appear, but every column from the original file show ( I have hid the columns for the snapshot)

Also here is example data if needed:

```
Material    Delivery Date   Desired Delivery    Delayed Days    Diff Deliv Date
20030650    1/3/2018    12/22/2017  12 days 00:00:00.000    12 days 00:00:00.00000
20056352    1/2/2018    12/31/2017  2 days 00:00:00.00000   2 days 00:00:00.000000
20052196    10/18/2018  10/18/2018  0 days 00:00:00.0000    0 days 00:00:00.0000000
20031687    1/3/2018    12/27/2017  7 days 00:00:00.0000    7 days 00:00:00.000000
20031687    2/3/2018    2/3/2018    0 days 00:00:00.00000   0 days 00:00:00.000000
20056053    5/14/2018   3/11/2017   429 days 00:00:00.00    429 days 00:00:00.0000000
20070547    1/2/2018    8/15/2017   140 days 00:00:00.0000  140 days 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Hey, can you give us the example data either as a csv or use the output of `df2.to_dict()`, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
df[late_deliveries].drop([DELIVERY_DATE, DESIRED_DATE], axis=1)
```

Is creating a *copy* of a view into the original dataframe with the given columns dropped, however you are not assigning this copy to anything. The original dataframe `df` is unchanged.

What you could do after creating df2 is:

```
df2 = df2[df2[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold]
df2.drop([DELIVERY_DATE, DESIRED_DATE], axis=1, inplace=True)
```